# What does ?! mean?

Tags: regex

What does the `?!` mean in the following regex expression?

```
new RegExp('http:\/\/(?!' + location.hostname + ')')
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which means that for the expression to match, the part within `(?!...)` *must not* match. In this case the regex matches `http://` *only* when it is not followed by the current host name (roughly, see Thilo's comment).

Comment: +1 or, because of lack of proper escaping, only if it is not followed by something similar to the host name, with dots replaced by stuff admissible.

Comment: Indeed. It probably won't make *that* much of a difference in most cases, though. Although, in the light of the recent Stripe CTF, such a lapse could be both hard to spot and may allow things that were not intended ;-)

Comment: Yes, won't matter. It's just that years of fixing injection vulnerabilities make these things stand out for me now ...

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Lookarounds".

Answer (score 6):

It's a negative lookahead, you can check [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's a look around.

`location.hostname` must not follow `http:\/\/`