# Regular Expression | REGEX for ICD9 codes

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python to extract ICD9 codes. And am using the below regular expression

```
icdRegex = recomp('V\d{2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{3}\.\d{1,2}|E\d{3}\.\d')
```

It captures pattern similar to 137.98 or V35.62

Everything works fine except the expression also captures patient weights as ICD9 code.

Now what I observed is, the weight is almost always appears as ex: 110.67 kg or kgs or lb or lbs

How do I separate ICD9 from weight !?

Comment: You might use a negative lookahead. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210807/what-does-mean)

Comment: I did try most of the stuff here on stackoverflow, but it wouldn't work. May be I am a little too dumb for regex.

Comment: [Bob's your uncle](http://regex101.com/r/bP5tV0/1).

Comment: Worked like charm !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead assertion like the follwing:

```
(V\d{2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{3}\.\d{1,2}|E\d{3}\.\d)\b(?!\s?(?:lb|kg)s?)
```

Comment: Something's missing... It still captures fat weights as ICD9 code

Answer (score 1):

Here is HamZa's expression for everyone:

```
icdRegex = recomp("\b(?:V\d{2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{3}\.\d{1,2}|E\d{3}\.\d)\b(?!\s*(?:kg|lb)s?\b)")
```

Thanks HamZa & Chapelo for helping out.
Appreciate it.

Comment: Guys... for the REGEX we wrote almost 2 month's back, failed on one condition. For numbers starting with 0 it is capturing wrong pattern. For example: if ICD9 code is 032.9, the expression will return it as 329. Any fix for codes starting with 0 !?

Comment: Further refinement to this thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200337/how-to-make-regex-ignore-a-pattern-following-a-specific-group)