# Jenkins Branches to Build - Exclude Single Branch

Tags: git, jenkins

Currently, using the setup displayed below, Jenkins builds `master` and all `*-preview` branches. Using ***Branches to build***, is it possible for Jenkins to exclude a single `*-preview` branch such as `exclude-this-branch-preview` while building all remaining `*-preview` branches?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex by specifying a semi-colon before

```
:^(?!exclude-this-branch-preview).*-preview$
```

From the help:

```
:<regular expression>
The syntax is of the form: :regexp. Regular expression syntax in branches to 
build will only build those branches whose names match the regular expression.
Examples:
:^(?!(origin/prefix)).*
    matches: origin or origin/master or origin/feature
    does not match: origin/prefix or origin/prefix_123 or origin/prefix-abc
:origin/release-\d{8}
    matches: origin/release-20150101
    does not match: origin/release-2015010 or origin/release-201501011 or 
    origin/release-20150101-something
:^(?!origin/master$|origin/develop$).*
    matches: origin/branch1 or origin/branch-2 or origin/master123 or 
    origin/develop-123
    does not match: origin/master or origin/develop
```

Comment: What does the leading `?` on `:^(?!exclude-this-branch-preview).*-preview$` imply?

Comment: @DanCat The `?!` is negative look ahead, which basically means must not match. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210807/what-does-mean

Answer (score 2):

```
:^(?!(<the branch name to be excluded with out angular braces>)).*
```

Put this in the branches to build and try SCM polling. Its a regular expression, self explanatory.